# What are the antonyms of "append" and "prepend"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

I need the antonyms for "append" (that is, I need a word that means "to *remove* at the end", since "append" means "to *add* at the end") and "prepend" (that is, I need a word that means "to *remove* at the beginning", since "prepend" means "to *add* at the beginning"). Do those words exist?

Would it be possible to use "behead" in a general context or is it limited to killing somebody?

Comment: To detach would be a good word for the antonym of append, and yes, programmers need to prepend and append all day

Comment: @BillFranke "remove" does not express the difference between the beginning and the end.

Comment: If this is for coding purposes, why not just make up your own terminology? FrontDelete vs. BackDelete, for instance.

Comment: It would help to know the context for these antonyms.

Comment: Don't look for single words.  Use *add to* or *remove from* in conjunction with *start* or *end*, depending.  Perl used *pop* and *push*, and *shift* and *unshift*, but I don't advise it.

Comment: "append" does not mean adding *at the end* specifically. i.e. it is not the antonym of prepend, but rather prepending is an example of appending.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could *[top and tail](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/top-and-tail)* something.

> to cut off the hard parts at each end of a fruit or vegetable when you
>   prepare it for cooking:  Top and tail the beans.

One can do this with gooseberries and runner beans and so forth, so I can't see why you shouldn't do it to something else.

Comment: Are "top" and "tail" used as verbs in this context? Normally they are not, are they?

Comment: @ceving, that's correct. Top and tail are verbs in this context, and used in a slightly unusual way. They both have other meanings as verbs but are more commonly nouns.

Answer (score 16):

"Truncate" means to remove part of something, usually at the end.

Comment: **truncate** − shorten (something) by cutting off the top or the end. Example: "a truncated cone shape". Synonyms: shorten, cut, cut short, curtail, bring to an untimely end.

Comment: Truncate is the best word for this application.

Answer (score 5):

In the generic sense, you could use *edit*, since, strictly speaking, removing is a form of editing. That would be much better than *behead*.

You might also consider the verb [***dele***](http://www.wordnik.com/words/dele), though. It means:

> To remove, especially from printed or written matter; delete.

That word itself won't tell you if the text to be deleted comes from the front or the back of written work, but you could specify that by saying, *"dele from the front,"* or, *"dele from the end."*

As Bill suggested, though, the words *remove* and *delete* would probably sound more natural. If any English words *do* mean "delete from the beginning" or "delete from the end of something," they don't spring to my mind.

If you wanted to use something informal, you might consider *lop off* or *chop off*. One dictionary defines *[lop](http://www.wordnik.com/words/lop)* as:

> To cut off as the top or extreme part of anything

so *lop off* might at least carry the implication that the text being deleted is from either the beginning or the end, and not the middle, whereas that might not be so for *remove* or *delete*.

Comment: So the answer is: they do not exist?

Comment: @ceving: Sorry, ceving, I don't have time to go through the entire dictionary this morning, and confirm that hypothesis. There are quite a few words in there I'm not familiar with; maybe the words you are looking for _are_ buried in there somewhere, I can't say for sure. My answer is, "If they exist, I don't believe they are commonly used." But someone else could chime in with an answer six hours from now that causes me to slap my forehead and think, "D'oh! Why didn't I remember that?" and then edit (or dele) my answer.

Comment: I vote for dele and lop.

Answer (score 5):

For queues or lists in a programming context, you probably want the following words:

- dequeue - Remove from the front of the list
- pop (or pull) - Remove from the end of the list

Comment: Depending on the programming language and context there is also "shift" to remove the first element from a list (and "unshift" to add elements to the start).

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is an old thread, but if you still want to differentiate between removing from the front or the back, you could build on @gmcgath's and @Bryce's suggestions.

They say that "truncate" usually means to cut off the end. So why not use "precate" to cut off the front. I have no doubt that your readers will know what you meant.

Comment: *Truncate* means "take back to the trunk, the main stem" so one can't form *precate:* the suffix is not *-cate.*

Comment: and _predicate_ could mean to remove the first two items. ;-)  (ad absurdum to underscore Andrew's comment)